# Post JSON Data to API with credentials PHP 4

Tags: php, json, api, restful-authentication, php4

I have an issue and I am in need of some help. I have PHP version 4.4.7 and I want to POST data in API which uses MVC pattern and json data. I tried with `get_file_contents` method but i get 405 Error.

I want to pass three variable in the link below

```
http:...../api/create_customer?x=test&y=test1&y=test3
```

`create_customer` is the method I have to call and pass attributes.
What does this version of PHP supports in order to connect with the credentials and post the data to the API. The possibility of upgrading the version is impossible so I have to find a way to do it in the current version.

Comment: PHP 4 support ended **8** years ago. You should seriously considering updating your PHP version.

Comment: Can you be more specific how you actually calling the the API. Post the part of the code where you doing the call.

Comment: Maybe you are POSTing data, try PUTing data.

Comment: File_get_contents(‘https://username:password@test.com/api/create_customer?var1=123&var2=test@test.gr&var3=5’)

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl.
Example given below:

$content = json_encode($content);

$credentials = $userName . ':' . $password;

```
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => $credentials,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json') ,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $content,
        //Debug
        //CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1
    );

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: curl is not added in the library how i am going to use it, it say curl init is not recognized

Comment: Enable CURL via the php.inI
Locate your PHP.ini file. (normally located at in the bin folder of your apache install e.g.
Open the PHP.ini in notepad.
Search or find the following : ';extension=php_curl.dll'
Uncomment this by removing the semi-colon ';' before it.
Save and Close PHP.ini.
Restart Apache.